# floatrow - Empty beside caption takes up too much space

Tags: floats, subfloats, floatrow

I have a row of floats using the `floatrow` package. I'd like each on to be labeled, but the caption to be empty. When I use `capposition=beside, capbesideposition={center, left}`, the label is too far away from the actual float and takes up too much space.

Example:

```
\tikzset{
    sort node/.style = {
        rectangle,
        draw = black,
        anchor = north west
    },
    curs node/.style = {
        sort node,
        text = white,
        fill = black
    },
    comp node/.style = {
        sort node,
        fill = gray
    }
}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \floatsetup{valign=t, heightadjust=object, capposition=beside, capbesideposition={center, left}}
    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
        \centering
        \floatbox{figure}{\caption{}}{
            \tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-01}
            \scalebox{1.5}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node at (0,0)          [comp node, label={\tiny 1}] (a) {5};
                    \node at (a.north east) [curs node, label={\tiny 2}] (b) {2};
                    \node at (b.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 3}] (c) {4};
                    \node at (c.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 4}] (d) {6};
                    \node at (d.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 5}] (e) {1};
                    \node at (e.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 6}] (f) {3};

                    \draw [-{Stealth[length=1mm]}, gray] (a.290) to[out=270, in=270, looseness=2] (b.250);
                    \draw [-{Stealth[length=1mm]}]       (b.300) to[out=270, in=270, looseness=2] (a.240);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
        \floatbox{figure}{\caption{}}{
            \tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-02}
            \scalebox{1.5}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node at (0,0)          [comp node, label={\tiny 1}] (a) {2};
                    \node at (a.north east) [comp node, label={\tiny 2}] (b) {5};
                    \node at (b.north east) [curs node, label={\tiny 3}] (c) {4};
                    \node at (c.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 4}] (d) {6};
                    \node at (d.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 5}] (e) {1};
                    \node at (e.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 6}] (f) {3};

                    \draw [-{Stealth[length=1mm]}, gray] (b.290) to[out=270, in=270, looseness=2] (c.250);
                    \draw [-{Stealth[length=1mm]}]       (c.300) to[out=270, in=270, looseness=2] (b.240);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
        \floatbox{figure}{\caption{}}{
            \tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-03}
            \scalebox{1.5}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node at (0,0)          [sort node, label={\tiny 1}] (a) {2};
                    \node at (a.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 2}] (b) {4};
                    \node at (b.north east) [comp node, label={\tiny 3}] (c) {5};
                    \node at (c.north east) [curs node, label={\tiny 4}] (d) {6};
                    \node at (d.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 5}] (e) {1};
                    \node at (e.north east) [sort node, label={\tiny 6}] (f) {3};

                    \draw [-{Stealth[length=1mm]}] (d.300) to[out=270, in=270, looseness=4] (d.240);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
    \end{subfloatrow}
\end{figure}
```

Produces:
[image: Sample 1]

When I change `capbesidewidth`, all that changes is the distance from the previous float:

[image: Sample 2]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can compile as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using `\sidesubfloat` instead `\floatbox` I was able to obtain the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Is this what you looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain, subcapbesideposition=center}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{
     node distance = 0pt,
   box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=gray!80, fill=#1, text=#2,
                             minimum width=1em, minimum height=4ex, 
                             inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
                             on chain},
 every edge/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=1mm]}, out=270, in=270, looseness=2.4},
every label/.style = {font=\tiny}
            }
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:a}]{%\tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-01}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = A going right]
\node[box=black/white, label=1]     {5};    % A-1: node name
\node[box=gray/black,  label=2]     {2};
\node[box=white/black, label=3]     {4};
\node[box=white/black, label=4]     {6};
\node[box=white/black, label=5]     {1};
\node[box=white/black, label=6]     {3};    % A-6
%
\path   (A-1.280) edge (A-2.260)
        (A-2.290) edge (A-1.250);
    \end{tikzpicture}
                            }
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:a}]{%\tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-02}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = B going right]
\node[box=gray/black,  label=1]     {2};    % B-1: node name
\node[box=gray/black,  label=2]     {5};
\node[box=white/black, label=3]     {4};
\node[box=black/white, label=4]     {6};
\node[box=black/white, label=5]     {1};
\node[box=black/white, label=6]     {3};    % B-6
%
\path   (B-2.280) edge (B-3.260)
        (B-3.290) edge (B-2.250);
    \end{tikzpicture}
                            }
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:a}]{%\tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter02-insertion-sort-03}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = C going right]
\node[box=black/white, label=1]     {5};    % C-1: node name
\node[box=black/white, label=2]     {4};
\node[box=gray/black, label=3]      {5};
\node[box=white/black, label=4]     {6};
\node[box=black/white, label=5]     {1};
\node[box=black/white, label=6]     {3};    % C-6
%
\path   (C-4.290) edge (C-3.250);
    \end{tikzpicture}
                            }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is what I want, but now I lose the benefit of `valign=t`, so if my figures are different heights (depending on arrow size) then they aren't aligned anymore. Also, thanks for the additional improvement that you made.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick, you can change `subcapbesideposition` from `center` to `top` and images will be aligned to their top. For test than in one picture add to one edge option `[looseness=4]` and see difference, e.g. if result is more acceptable to you.